# How to toggle Bootstrap 5 accordion component via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, bootstrap-5

I'm using the accordion component from Bootstrap 5 and I want to toggle the component from my own JavaScript function (`toggle` in the example below). Preferably without having to include jQuery.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="toggle(event)">Toggle Accordion Item #1</button>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
// Toggle Accordion Item #1
function toggle(event) {
  // ???
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Snippet put together from the examples at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the docs for the [collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="toggle(event)">Toggle Accordion Item #1</button>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
// Toggle Accordion Item #1
function toggle(event) {
  var myCollapse = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse')[0];
  var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
    toggle: true
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#how-it-works

Answer (score 1):

I updated the toggle function to toggle all accordions on the page.

```
function toggle(event)
{
    //in my sbUCR.aspx i put a button on the nav bar to call this
    //<button class="btn btn-outline" type="button" onclick="toggle(event)" id="btoggle">▲</button>
    var myCollapse2 = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse');
    for (let i = myCollapse2.length-1; i > 0; i--) //go backwards to 1 b/c 0 is the actual navbar hamburger menu
    {
        //console.log("found" + myCollapse2[i].id);
        var bsCollapse2 = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse2[i], {
            toggle: true
        });
    }
}
```